# How to enable lazy loading of relations after INSERT in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I have a one to many relationship between two entities in NHibernate:

```
public class Application
{
    public string TaskId { get; set; } // Foreign key reference
    public Task Task { get; set; }     // The relation/navigation property
}
```

The `db.Web.Applications.Create` method just calls the "SaveOrUpdate" method of the NHibernate session inside a transaction.

The relavant mappings:

```
internal class ApplicationMap : ClassMap<Application>
{
    public ApplicationMap() : base()
    {
        Schema(...);
        Table(...);

        CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(app => app.UserId, "...")
            .KeyProperty(app => app.TaskId, "task_id")
            .KeyProperty(app => app.TransactionId, "...");

        // Relations

        References(app => app.Task, "task_id")
            .ForeignKey("taskid")
            .Unique()
            .Not.Insert()
            .Cascade.Persist();
    }
}

internal class TaskMap : ClassMap<Task>
{
    public TaskMap()
    {
        Schema(..);
        Table(...);

        Id(task => task.Id, "task_id");

        HasMany(task => task.Applications)
            .KeyColumn("task_id");
    }
}
```

When I wrote a test against a real database to create a new `Application` I found that the navigation property was not lazy loading after insert:

```
var app = new Application(...)
{
    TaskId = "..."
};

db.Web.Applications.Create(app);
db.SaveChanges();

var actual = db.Web.Applications.Find(app.UserId, app.TaskId, app.TransactionId);

// actual.Task is null
```

The mappings are working as I expect, but after inserting a new `Application` object, accessing the `Task` property returns `null` instead of lazy loading that entity from the database. Can this be done, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem comes in with the way you've mapped the `Application` class and it's corresponding `Task` object relation.  I think you should map it like this instead:

```
public class Application
{
    public Task Task { get; set; }     // The relation/navigation property
}

internal class ApplicationMap : ClassMap<Application>
{
    public ApplicationMap() : base()
    {
        Schema(...);
        Table(...);

        CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(app => app.UserId, "...")
            .KeyReference(app => app.Task, "task_id")
            .KeyProperty(app => app.TransactionId, "...");
    }
}

internal class TaskMap : ClassMap<Task>
{
    public TaskMap()
    {
        Schema(..);
        Table(...);

        Id(task => task.Id, "task_id");

        HasMany(task => task.Applications)
            .KeyColumn("task_id");
    }
}
```

There is no need to map a specific id property for the foreign key relationships.  I ALWAYS map the entity only.  It's much easier this way.  Then your code above for insertion would be this:

```
var app = new Application(...)
{
    Task = session.Load<Task>(taskId)
};

db.Web.Applications.Create(app);
db.SaveChanges();

var actual = db.Web.Applications.Find(app.UserId, app.TaskId, app.TransactionId);
```

Comment: The problem is I need the task Id everywhere. I'll try this mapping technique and maybe create a custom getter property for the TaskId instead of having to type `app.Task.Id` all the time.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Is it really that big of a difference to do `app.Task.Id` vs `app.TaskId` ?  We do this everywhere in our code with relationships like this.  Also this way you don't have to double map the same thing.

Comment: I see what I was doing wrong now. At first I didn't go for this solution because, generally, I try to call methods or properties directly on the object and not the object's properties, because this creates code that is easier to refactor in the future. I thought merely including a `public string TaskId { get { return Task.Id; } }` delegate property in the `Application` class mucked up the mapping, but I was using the `TaskId` delegate property in a `QueryOver` call. _This_ is what screwed up NHibernate. I needed `session.QueryOver<Application>().Where(app => app.Task.Id == "...")`.

Comment: Yeah a good rule of thumb I keep in mind is that if it's not in the mapping you can't query on it.

Comment: Now I'm getting "Unable to cast object of type 'TaskProxy' to type 'System.String'" when I query for an application using `QueryOver().Where(app => app.Task.Id == "...")`. I just can't win with this. I'm about ready to give up on this relation as part of the composite key.

Comment: Is `Task.Id` really a string?  If not then `app.Task.Id == "..."` won't work. If it is a string then judging by the error it looks like you are doing something like this instead: `.Where(x => x.Task.Id == <task object>` which is not allowed.  You would have to do something like this `.Where(x => x.Task.Id == <task object>.Id)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74345/discussion-between-greg-burghardt-and-cole-w).